# Citations not working, bibliography not showing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I assume the bibliography only shows the cited sources, so the real root of the problem is with the citation, but I'm not sure. This is what I have in my latex document now.

```
.
.
.

\usepackage[sorting=ydnt,bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{uni.bib}

\pagenumbering{plain}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

.
.
.

miscellaneous citation \parencite[see][page 72]{example}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Bibliography}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And in uni.bib (same directory)

```
@book{example,
    author = {Author, Example},
    title = {Example Book},
    year = {2020},
    PUBLISHER = {Example Publisher}
    }
```

This seems like it should work, but the citation reads "miscellaneous citation [**example**]" and the bibliography section is just an otherwise empty page that says "Bibliography". Note that "\addbibresource{uni.bib}" is shown in bold and entirely yellow (my colour for latex commands).
This is probably something pretty obvious, but it still eludes me. I've looked through forums and found nothing that worked, and so I come here seeking your help.

Comment: Did you already compile your document using biber? See also [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/134144)

Comment: There should be no need for `\printbibheading` when you have `\printbibliography`. The symptoms you describe so far suggest that you failed to run Biber. The link in leandriis' comment above explains why you need to do that. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains what you can do to make your editor run Biber for you.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but you shouldn't need the "`pages`" in `\parencite[see][page 72]{example}`. Usually `\parencite[see][72]{example}` is better as it automatically includes a page prefix depending on your style.

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to run Biber on your document as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864? Did that help? If not, please tell us exactly what you tried and post the contents of the `.blg` (Biber's log file) and the `.log` file here.